# fill the nulls of a column with the mean sum of the division of two columns multiplied by one column minus the previous column SAS

Tags: sql, null, sas, missing-data, proc-sql

I need to fill the nulls of a column with the mean sum of the division of two columns multiplied by one column and rest the previous An example would be

```
A B_01 B_02 ... B_60
5  .    .
5  2    3
7  3   1,2
9  3   0,3
4  .    .
```

Well, I would like the missing value for column B_01 to be (2/5 + 3/7 + 3/9) / 3 * its corresponding column A
For column B_02(3/5 + 1,2/7 + 0,3/9)/3 * its corresponding column A - his new value in B_01

I have thought about doing this, but it turns out that I have 60 columns with which to do it and the only way it comes to mi mind is to do this 60 times.

```
Proc sql;
  create table new as
  Select *
  , sum(B_01/A)/sum(case when B_01 is missimg then . else 1)*A end as new_B_01
  , sum(B_02/A)/sum(case when B_02 is missimg then . else 1)*A-B_01 end as new_B_02
  from table_one
  ;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can generate such a wallpaper of code using macro.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want.

```
data test;
   input A B_01-B_02;
   cards;
5  .    .
5  2    3
7  3   1.2
9  3   0.3
4  .    .
;;;;

data test2;
   set test;
   array B_ B_01-B_02;
   array M_[2];
   do i = 1 to dim(m_);
      if not missing(b_[i]) then m_[i]= divide(b_[i],a);
      end;
   drop i;
   run;
proc print;
    run; 
proc stdize reponly  missing=mean data=test2 out=mean;
   var m_:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;   
data mean2;
   set mean;
   array B_ B_01-B_02;
   array M_[2];
   do i = 1 to dim(m_);
      b_[i] = coalesce(b_[i],m_[i]);
      end;
   drop i m_:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: I the original request was to use A times the mean.  So `b_[i] = coalesce(b_[i],a*m_[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
data test;
   input A B_01-B_02;
   cards;
5  .    .
5  2    3
7  3   1.2
9  3   0.3
4  .    .
;;;;
run;



data mean;
set test end=eof;
array b(*) b_:;
array sumb(2) _temporary_;
array cntb(2) _temporary_;
array mean_b_(2);

* cumulative sums and counts;
do i = 1 to dim(b);
    sumb(i) = sum(sumb(i), b(i)/a);
    if not missing(b(i)) then cntb(i) + 1;
end;

* mean;
if eof then do;
    do i = 1 to dim(b);
        mean_b_(i) = sumb(i)/cntb(i);
    end;
    output;
end;
keep mean_:;
run;



data test2;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    set mean;
    array mean_b_(*) mean_b:;
end;

set test;
array b_(*) b_:;
array new_b_(2);

do i = 1 to dim(b_);
    if i = 1 then new_b_(i) = coalesce(b_(i), mean_b_(i) * a);
    else new_b_(i) = coalesce(b_(i), mean_b_(i) * a - new_b_(i-1));
end;
run;
```